# Using Jquery to get numeric value which is in between "/" in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to fetch numeric value from link like this.

Example link

/produkt/114664/bergans-of-norway-airojohka-jakke-herre

So I need to fetch 114664.

I have used following jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var outputv = $('.-thumbnail a').map(function() {
        return this.href.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    }).get();
    console.log( outputv );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2qL5oyp/1/

The issue I am facing is that in some cases I have urls like this

/produkt/114664/bergans-of-norway-**3**airojohka-**3**jakke-herre

Here I have **"3"** inside text string, so in my code I am actually getting the output as "11466433" But I only need 114664

So is there any possibility i can get numeric values only after /produkt/ ?

Comment: I used this: /^[a-zA-Z\/]+(\d+)/ and it worked on some testing sites. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that the path structure of your link will always be like in your question, it's safe to do this:

```
var path = '/produkt/114664/bergans-of-norway-airojohka-jakke-herre';
var id   = path.split('/')[2];
```

This splits the string up by '/' into an array, where you can easily reference your desired value from there.

Comment: yes the url structure will always start from /produkt/{NUMERIC_VALUE}/{OTHER VALUES}
So I need the numeric values in between /produkt/ and /other_values

Comment: Cool, but be careful - the string must start with a `/` for the the index `[2]` to be right. If not, the correct index in this case would be `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numerical part after `/produkt/` (without limitiation where that might be...) use a regular expression, match against the string:

```js
var str = '/produkt/114664/bergans-of-norway-3airojohka-3jakke-herre';
alert(str.match(/\/produkt\/(\d+)/)[1])
```

(Note: In the real code you need to make sure `.match()` returned a valid array before accessing `[1]`)